# Sharepoint 365 feature resources bug

Tags: office-365, 2013, resource-files

After Sharepoint 365 update (end 09.11.2012) resources string in list definition start display as:

$Resources:_FeatureId{AC83475A-588E-4876-BB71-24524023F731},FieldSortOrderDisplayName;

Field definition:

```
<Field Name="SortOrder" 
   ID="{612ffa3a-3842-404d-a88a-f17fad13a874}" 
   DisplayName="$Resources:FieldSortOrderDisplayName;" 
   Type="Number" Decimals="0" Required="TRUE">
```

or

```
<Field Name="SortOrder" 
   ID="{612ffa3a-3842-404d-a88a-f17fad13a874}" 
   DisplayName="$Resources:_Res,FieldSortOrderDisplayName;" 
   Type="Number" Decimals="0" Required="TRUE">
```

The same result.
How to resolve?

Answer (score 1):

If there's nothing you did to "break" that, I suggest opening a [Service Request](http://portal.microsoftonline.com) through MS online portal or hard coding the DisplayName. Hard coding is a dirty workaround if you need to get it fixed quickly, and not generally a good idea.

Or it just might start working tomorrow if you wait. Wonders of SharePoint Online.

Comment: Hello, how to open "a Service Request through MS online portal"?

Comment: +! for the "Or it just might start working tomorrow if you wait" this should be the mantra of SharePoint Online.

Comment: Added link to Online Portal where you open Service Requests. You need to be administrator, though.

Comment: Downvote if you like, but Online is a black box and it is impossible to provide detailed answers.